# Reg for (int index = 3; index-- > 1;)

Tags: java

I have the doubt regarding the for loop execution when i execute the following piece of code

```
public class LoopTest
{
    public static void main (String... args) {
        int num = 3;
        do {
            for (int index = 3; index-- > 1;)
                System.out.print("index value:" + index + "\n");
            System.out.print("num:" + num + "\n");
        } while (num-- > 1);
        System.out.print("num:" + num + "\n");
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
index value:2
index value:1
num:3
index value:2
index value:1
num:2
index value:2
index value:1
num:1
num:0
```

I completely don't understand how the value of index is 2 instead of 3,also 1 get printed inspite of the condition in the for loop "index-- > 1"
Expecting  reply as soon as possible

Thanks in advance,
Nusrath.

Comment: Don't do that inlining magic, there is no case in real life where it could be useful in any way.

Comment: Just a comment, indenting your code correctly helps a lot when you're trying to understand it.

Comment: Using a debugger to step through each line of code is a good way to "completely" understand what each line of code is doing. ;)

Answer (score 7):

1) You're decrementing `index` part of the *condition*, which executes before even the first iteration. That's why you're seeing index=2 in the first iteration.

2) You're using the postfix-decrement in the condition, which means "decrement, but the result of the expression is the original value" which is why you're seeing index=1 - when index is 2, the condition is met but index is decremented to 1.

Basically, it would be a lot cleaner if this were written as:

```
for (int index = 3; index > 1; index--)
```

I'd also suggest you make a similar change to your

```
while (num-- > 1)
```

loop. Basically, mixing side-effecting operators and conditions is *almost always* a bad idea. It generally makes the code much harder to read and understand - as this question basically proves.

Additionally, it *definitely* helps if you use braces for *every* `for` loop. So instead of this:

```
for (int index = 3; index-- > 1;)
    System.out.print("index value:" + index + "\n");
```

Write this:

```
for (int index = 3; index > 1; index--) {
    System.out.print("index value:" + index + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I completely don't understand how the value of index is 2 instead of 3

This is the order of execution for iterations where the condition passes:

```
index = 3;
index--;
System.out.print("index value:" + index + "\n");
index--;
System.out.print("index value:" + index + "\n");
```

That is why you get index values of 2 and 1.

The reason why you can get an `index` value of 1 inside of the body of the loop is because in the condition, `index--` returns `index` and then decrements `index`. Perhaps what you're wanting is:

```
for (int index = 3; index > 1; index--)
```

Which will get to the body of the `for` loop with index values of 3 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

In a `for` loop, the condition is executed *before* each loop, including the *first* loop. So, the order of execution is:

1. `int index = 3;`
2. `index--;`
3. test for `index > 1`
4. execute loop
5. goto 2.

As you can see, at the start of the first loop, index will be `2`

Answer (score 0):

After you compared

```
index-- > 1
```

The index is decreased. 
To solve this just use the default for loop:

```
for(int index = 3; index > 1; index--)
{
   ... code
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.